# Unusually cratered asteroid

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, asteroids

Asteroid Mathilde is a rocky body in the solar system that seems to be more crater than asteroid.

[image: asteroid Mathilde]

Are these impact craters? If so, how did this body survive the impacts? It seems at first glance that it should have shattered if these craters were caused by impacts.

Comment: Probably more suited to [astronomy.se]

Comment: Tangentially, there seem to be quite a lot of smaller craters exactly on the rim of this large crater shown in the picture, yet none are visible on the interior of that crater. An explanation for those craters as impacts would seem to torture probabilistic thinking. Remarkable coincidence.

Comment: It's not really an astronomy question, this deals with material strength, forces and so on, not its position relative to such and such zodiacal construct. Pure physics. In other words we could have the same discussion if we find this rock laying in a ditch by the side of the road.

Comment: Asteroids are most certainly a subject for astronomy.  Impact craters are most definitely a subject for astronomy.  No idea who you think arranged to send out a probe to take that photo but I'm pretty sure astronomers are going to figure prominently.

Comment: @SmedleyButler "not its position relative to such and such zodiacal construct." Perhaps you are confusing astronomy and astrology?

Comment: @SmedleyButler : "An explanation for those craters as impacts would seem to torture probabilistic thinking." First, the big crater may be younger than most of the smaller craters, second, the solid angle from which the surface of the big crater can be hit is smaller than for the crater's edges.

Comment: Yes, we discuss asteroid formation on Astronomy.SE. ;) Eg, https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/49425/16685 Also see https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/tools/sbdb_lookup.html#/?sstr=mathilde & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/253_Mathilde

Comment: My question wasn't about asteroid formation. It's a simple physics question. Can impacts do this to rock. And suggesting small craters that overlap both sides of the rim of a larger crater were excavated before the larger crater strains credibility to the extreme.

Answer (score 0):

My impression is the crater at the front has a cylindrical shape, so maybe a high-velocity body moved from "top" to "bottom", off the center of the asteroid, and removed all matter it met on its way. Similar to a fast bullet leaving only a narrow trace in, say, glass.

Comment: My *guess* is that a larger body was fractured during a collision with a body of similar mass, and Mathilde is one of the remnants. Note that Mathilde has a rather low density (~1.3 g/cm³), so it "may be more of a loosely-packed pile of material than solid rock". It has a high carbon content, and the density indicates that it probably doesn't have much metallic content. It'd be interesting to know how much ice it contains.

Answer (score 0):

Asteroids are heavily cratered because of a long history of impacts with other asteroids/ comets. Old impact craters on asteroids have been deformed and erased by newer impact craters.